# include on instantiate PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, include

Well I have a question. On Zend Framework We use a very interesting structure because if you intanciate a class then automatically Zend include the class file and after instanciate it (Class obviously allow to ge the directory's structure Class: abc_def_pqr then path is abc/def/pgr.php)

Does anyone have any idea???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework uses [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to register a function that is called when a class is called but does not exist.

The function then does as you say, replace the underscores with directory separators and tries to include the file.

See [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) but note using spl_autoload_register instead of __autoload allows for multiple autoload functions, which is better practice. Especially if being used in conjunction with ZF or external libraries.